# How Java keeps reference to a Stack?

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

Code:

```
    Stack<Integer> firstStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<Integer> secondStack = firstStack;

    firstStack.push(1);
    firstStack.push(2);

    secondStack.pop();
    System.out.println(firstStack.pop());
```

My question is, if firstStack references the last item in the Stack and secondStack also references this item, when I pop from the secondStack, the firstStack should keep referencing the ( previous ) last item( which is 2 ). How come the reference of the firstStack changes to the first item as well? ( by first item I mean: 1 )

Comment: standard java. You have one object with two names.

Comment: I know this. My question is how can this work? How does the element that firstStack points to changes? How is this possible?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but this is not really what I am trying to ask..

I guess I need to ask a much more detailed question to express myself.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699861/standart-stack-implementation-and-java Thank you everyone for answering the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually stack in java is implemented using Vector class.

Vector class has following attributes ( you can cross check by looking at implementation of Vector class)

```
   protected Object elementData[];
   protected int elementCount;
   protected int capacityIncrement;
```

So internally it stores data in an array and also keeps track of increment and count using other 2 clas attributes. So internally your **firstStack** and **secondStack** references point to the same elementData, elementCount and capacityIncrement attributes. Hence you get consistent results.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my question and answering it.

Answer (score 7):

Both `firstStack` and `secondStack` refer to the stack itself, not the last object in the stack.

When you do

```
Stack<Integer> secondStack = firstStack;
```

you're saying: Take the stack object that `firstStack` refers to, and let `secondStack` refer to the same object. No copying of the stack is done, or similar.

Thus, if you pop from `secondStack`, you also pop from `firstStack`.

Comment: I know this and thanks for your clear answer. My question is. When I pop from secondStack, how does it say "Change what the firstStack references to" as well?

Does all elements in a stack have a reference to the Stack reference as well?

Comment: @KorayTugay: the problem I think is that you havent understood the answer. There is only one stack!

Comment: @carlosdc What is a Stack? Just an object with a reference to the first element it holds only. When you push an other element to the stack, the first element now holds a reference to the previous element in the stack, and your Stack reference itself now holds a reference to the new object. When you push another object, .. well you get the idea.

I understand the answer 100%. What I do not understand is, how the reference of the firstStack also changes.

Question is more about the implementation of the Stack actually!

Comment: @KorayTugay `Stack` is a Java class. Please imagine its name is actually `Klomp` and see if you understand any better.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik I have no problems with the names. My question is not clear enough obviously. I will ask another question.

Comment: @KorayTugay: Both of them point at the same object. Thus, when we was firstStack what it's first element is, it's the same as asking secondStack. They're both the same object, by two different names.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm I will just ask another question. I know they both point to the same object.

Comment: @Koray: Imagine taking a paper tray, and putting two post-its on it: `A` and `B`. Then put 2 pieces of paper saying "1" and "2" into the tray labelled `A`. Then remove the top piece from the tray labelled `B`. Then remove the top one from the tray labelled `A`. That's what you're doing.

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm Thanks. Please see rai.skumar response and my comment on the question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No. Here `Stack object` is one and two references `firstStack and secondStack` both referring the same `Stack Object`. Any operation though any reference of this will effect on same object as both are referring same Object.

```
Stack<Integer> secondStack = firstStack;
```

This is not new Object creation and `secondStack` will refer what `firstStack` is referring.

Answer (score 0):

`firstStack`  and `secondStack` are just reference to actual Stack object so even you perform pop/push on any of this you are updating the same Stack object.